# jQuery: if ($('#indicador').width()

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

I was able to make a bar to animate to width 150px. Now I try to make it come back to its original position but only when it reaches the end. Why the conditional: if ($('#indicator').width() > '149px') doesn't work? How to do this well?

```
$(function(){        
  $("#play").click(function() {
    $("#indicator").animate({"width": "150px"}, 8400);
  });

  // indicador back to 0
  if ($('#indicator').width() > '149px') {
      $("#indicator").animate({"width": "1px"}, 100);
  }
});
```

Here to check and play: http://jsfiddle.net/SwkaR/

Comment: Your second function is run immediately after your DOM is ready, so it will not fire when your animation is completed!

Comment: `console.log( $('#indicator').width() );` should show you why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Question 1

Your function for returning the indicator to it's original position is fired immediately after the DOM is ready (`$(function() { /* code for when the dom is ready */ });`.

#### Question 2

Since Javascript is async, you should create a callback for your animation :

```
$(function(){

  $("#play").click(function() {
      $("#indicator").animate({"width": "150px"}, { duration: 8400, complete: function() {
          $("#indicator").animate({"width": "1px"}, 100);
      }});
  });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zEwHx/

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($('#indicator').width() > 149)
```

jQuery `width()` function returns an integer of width value, not string with also the unit in which it is e.g. px.

Your have logical error in the program. You can chain `animate()` functions. Once, the first function is completed it will automatically move to 2nd.

```
$(function(){
  $("#play").click(function() {
      $("#indicator").animate({"width": "150px"}, 8400).animate({ "width" : "1px" }, 100);
  });
});
```

Comment: I put your answer here and it does not seem to work. Waht am I missing? :http://jsfiddle.net/SwkaR/2/

Comment: but in the fiddle its working :D I have tested 5 times @drinchev

Comment: Yes, yes you are right about this ;) that's why I deleted my comment!

Comment: I still don't understand very well why this doesn't work?: jsfiddle.net/SwkaR/2 Your first answer with the condition makes sense.

Comment: well, it does not works because the condition you have given in IF statement is checked only for one time (on DOM load) and it does not check for condition again and again. I posted about `.width()` first because i didn't opened your fiddle and didn't caught your logical mistake.

Answer (score 1):

[Width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) returns a number:

> The difference between .css(width) and .width() is that the latter
>   returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do arithmetic comparison on a string like `'149px'`.  Instead you need to use `> 149`.  Or better yet (more readable), `>= 150`

Answer (score 0):

Try this... not use `$(function)` use the `.on`...

```
$("#play").on('click', function() {  
      $("#indicator").animate({"width": "150px"}, {duration:8400, complete:function(){
          $("#indicator").animate({"width": "1px"}, 100);
      }});
});
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SwkaR/5/)